# Python - Convert String to an Object or Array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, object

I have the data below stored in a variable `data_str` which have a class string.

```
 level  page_num    block_num   par_num line_num    word_num    left    top width   height  conf    text
 1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   500 659 -1  
 2  1   1   0   0   0   35  41  422 560 -1  
 3  1   1   1   0   0   44  41  406 203 -1  
 4  1   1   1   1   0   98  41  341 10  -1  
 5  1   1   1   1   1   98  42  31  8   70  ‘When
 5  1   1   1   1   2   135 42  17  8   75  Dr.
 5  1   1   1   1   3   160 41  32  9   92  Umali
 5  1   1   1   1   4   197 44  25  6   96  rose
 5  1   1   1   1   5   227 42  11  8   96  to
 5  1   1   1   1   6   243 41  17  9   93  the
 5  1   1   1   1   7   265 41  52  10  91  deanship
 5  1   1   1   1   8   322 41  11  9   96  of
 5  1   1   1   1   9   337 41  18  8   96  the
 5  1   1   1   1   10  361 41  27  9   80  U.P.
 5  1   1   1   1   11  394 41  45  10  85  College
```

Every time I access `data_str[0]` it returns `l` . I want to access the first line and every cell element of it. In other words I want to make it as an object so I can access every cell of it easily. How will I do it in Python? Please help.

Comment: How is that data represented in python? Is that a dataframe?

Comment: @Alyssa Gono you need to convert string into pandas data frame or numpy array

Comment: Are  you getting `data_str ` from a text or a csv file?

Comment: @Rakesh -> its return by a library function.

Comment: Try `print(repr(data_str))` to get what it looks like of your string first.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh --> It was just a string class variable. When I run print(type(data_str)) , it returns class 'str'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strings are arrays in python, so `data_str[0]` means getting the character at position 0, that is `l`

So you can:

- Split the string by row to retrieve a list of row.
- For each row, split it to obtain items for each row.

Something like this

```py
rows = data_str.splitlines()
arr = [row.split() for row in rows]
# now you can access item at row 1, column 2 like arr[1][2]
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's stored in string,

```
cells = data_str.split('\n')[1].split('\s') # first line in list

# all lines
lines = [line.split() for line in data_str.split('\n')]
```

Or using `csv` lib to handle the whole string:

```
from io import StringIO # Python 3
import csv

f = StringIO(data_str)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\s')

lines = [row for row in reader]
# first line
cells = lines[1]
```

Comment: Is there no easy way to do it?

Comment: @AlyssaGono in what sense of "easy"? Which lib you wanna pick? It's pure python. That seems easy enough for me.